# How to select (and alter) an svg already appended to dom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 chart that I append to the dom. If I included the code below, the chart would animate immediately. However, I don't want that to happen. Therefore, I want to add the transition later -- I run the same function again that added the chart but using if/else statements, I avoid appending the chart a second time and instead run the code below--the problem is that the chart doesn't animate now. I'm wondering if it's because I'm not providing enough information about what to select-- `({})` isn't specific enough?--, or if it's potentially another issue?

```
                 var transition = d3.select({}).transition()
                    .duration(250)
                    .ease("linear");
                    var that = this;
```

Comment: I can confirm that `d3.select({})` isn't going to select anything.  If you want more help than that you'll have to a little more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added the d3 chart earlier you probably stored a reference to the svg?

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr({/*...*/}); // etc.
```

Assuming the above practice you can reuse the variable:

```
svg.transition().duration(250).ease("linear");
```

If you must do a select later you have to use a string for the select statement:

```
d3.select('svg').duration(250).ease("linear");
// selects the first <SVG> tag found in the DOM
```